# My alertview for the UIWebView doesn't work

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, alertview

Why doesn't this code work? All I have is this:

```
-(void)_webview:(UIWebView *)_webview didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"You have no internet connection!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    exit(0);
}
```

It should work, right?

Comment: what do you mean by `doesn't work` , does it give any errors? do you have `<UIAlertViewDelegate>` in your .h file?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html

Comment: Also, this has **absolutely nothing to do with Xcode whatsoever.**

Comment: I don't have <UIAlertViewDelegate> in my h file.

Comment: @user1941966 To receive UIAlertViewDelegate calls such as `didDismissWithButtonIndex:` you need to use `@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> `

Comment: That didn't change anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because you mistyped the name of the `UIWebViewDelegate` method. You have

```
_webview:didFailLoadWithError:
```

whereas the real name of this method is

```
webView:didFailLoadWithError:
```

Comment: I changed it, nothing changed.

Comment: @user1941966 Have you tried making **both** changes at the same time? I. e. mine and that of Fernando Mazzon?

Answer (score 0):

The delegate method is mistyped, as stated in the above response. Also, did you set the delegate of the UIWebView to the instance of the class that has those methods implemented?

for example, if it's a view controller, it could be in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _webView.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: That didn't change anything.